# Volley onResponse method not working

Tags: android, http, http-post, android-volley

I'm using Volley to send Post request.I'm trying to send jsonObject to server.This is my source

```
    public void sendDicieIDToServer(JSONObject jsonObject)
{


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

            Log.e("response is", "Response " + jsonObject.toString());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            NetworkResponse errorRes = volleyError.networkResponse;
            String stringData = "";
            if(errorRes != null && errorRes.data != null){
                try {
                    stringData = new String(errorRes.data,"UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.e("Error",stringData);

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Authorization",uhfScannerModel.getToken());

            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

            return params;
        }

    };
    HandsetApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);


}
```

I successfully created JsonObject and when I run my app and try to debug it, onErrorResponse method has called and stringData String contains real json result. I don't know what is a wrong and why onErrorResponse method calling.

Comment: What is the error response?

Comment: @akash93 JsonObject .I mean success json object (onResponse method)

Comment: You posted that `onErrorResponse` is called and `stringData` contains some json response. What is that json? Also check what  the status code of the response is

Comment: @ akash93  status code is 400

Comment: That translates to `Bad Request`. Most probably the `jsonObject` that your sending to the server is different from what it expects. Post contents of `stringData`  as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**User this link for Volley**

Here i made volley reusability where you can apiCall easy way..

https://github.com/sikander-kh/Volley-Reusability